# Can I use my Wi-Fi Router as a DHCP server for the rest of my network if I connect a switch into the ISP modem and connect items into the switch?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp, switch

I am finally getting fiber, but now have to figure out how to handle the traffic.

I was going to get a cheapish network switch such as this:
[TP-Link TL-SG3428X](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/omada-sdn-switch/tl-sg3428x/)

It has SPF+ connections that will allow me to receive the 5GB fiber connection in my garage.

Then from that switch I was going to run 1GB connections to all my other equipment (upper two levels), including my Wi-Fi router (first floor) which also has a 1GB connection.

Will all my devices that are hard wired to the switch (aka laptop/server) be able to get DHCP from my wireless router some how?

Most information I see say to have the connection come in to the Wi-Fi router and then go to the switch, but my Wi-Fi router (nor any others I have seen) support this type of LAN speeds.

Please help! I really don't want to have to spend over $1,000 on an edge router.

Comment: I think the devices that are wired to the switch need to be connected by Ethernet to the wireless router for them to get DHCP from the wireless router. You can a small switch at the wireless router to add ports or just move the existing switch to the LAN side of the wireless router.

Comment: How many public IPv4 addresses are you getting with that 5Gbps fiber connection? If just one, then you'll still need a NAT gateway at the head of your network that can keep up with your 5Gbps service. You could have a router with 1 Gbps ports elsewhere on your network do "NAT on a stick"/"one-armed NAT", but that would tank your Internet throughput to 1Gbps.

Comment: Yup, my goal is to have access to 5Gbps internet some how.  My Wifi devices can share 1Gbps, no remorse there, but my other devices, mainly my pc & server (not hooked up to the 1gb limited wifi router) need to be able to get and share up to the 5Gbps internet.  How can I do that?

Comment: You probably should get a much faster main router that can handle your higher speed AND do DCHP.  Probably forget using the Wireless Router as the DHCP server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its useful to look at what we need here first and the topology I am suggesting. DHCP can run *anywhere* on the network, and its just a service that sets up IPs within the network. You can even run a network without it. You're looking at the wrong thing. *Where* DHCP runs dosen't matter.

Your *firewall* does NAT - it takes the uplink, and does nat masquarading to essentially forward traffic as needed. That's the important thing here.

The capability of the *firewall* - both in terms of input bandwidth and ability to process is the important thing here. In theory the topology you want uses something similar to a [router on a stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_on_a_stick), but frankly just building out a firewall that can handle it is much better.

You need a *firewall* doing NAT that'll 1) take in a SFP+ module 2) share it out to a network/switch (via whatever media that'll work). While a modern 'wifi' consumer router *does* do DHCP, its really a firewall + a DHCP server + a wifi AP, and practically you can split these off . There's fairly low cost options that don't cost over a grand to do this- some of which are very similar to a 'consumer' router.

In a few months with wifi 7, there *should* be 10 gig capable consumer routers, but direct SFP input isn't going to be an option. I suspect its unlikely that there will be consumer gear that runs on optical any time soon. Essentially you're looking in the wrong place if you're 'just' looking at consumer routers. I could be wrong and its something to look at

There's *commercial* or *prosumer* options as well - something like the [UDM pro](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-unifi-os-consoles/products/udm-pro) would work - using the 10 gig wan port, and the other 10 gig wan port with a DAC to uplink to a switch (and/or using the existing switches). I'm 'accidentally' giving hardware recommendations here, but we have a specific site for that. Considering you're looking at a large rackmount router, this might be an alternative. Microtik and Unifi are the 'major' options here, but I'd be surprised if there isn't some obscure chinese company that makes fairly usable whitebox gear too. You *should* be looking at these routers for your needs.

Finally - you might want to consider building your own router. Hardware wise - the 'common'option is to take an old PC, throw in a second hand 10 gig capable card (there's a bunch of mellinox cards floating around for SFP).

These days though, there's really capable SFF boxen like the [R86s](https://www.servethehome.com/the-gowin-r86s-revolution-low-power-2-5gbe-and-10gbe-intel-nvidia/) - which has a varient with 2 SFP ports + 3 2.5 gig ports - reviews say it won't work with 2.5 or 5 gig SFPs so take this as an indication that such machines exist, rather than a specific recommendation.). In either case, SFP in, then a DAC to your actual switch. If it *wasn't* 5 gig or SFP - there's super common 4x 2.5 gig ethernet capable x86 boxen that would work. In general these are going to be a lot smaller, quieter and lighter.

While I built a router from scratch, you can probably go with pfsense, opensense or what ever router distro that tickles your fancy,

Essentially though - you *have* options that could fit your budget with a little research, and using a consumer wifi router here is a mistake

Comment: I am not familiar with the differences in standards in different regions, but do you think that this would be a suitable consumer product? https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-5590-fiber/

Comment: Well *potentially* - https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-5590-fiber/technical-specifications/ is where you need to look. The FRITZ!SFP XGS-PON module might work - *but* you may need to confirm what module you need with your ISP based on what standards they use, and if the modules for that standard will work with it

Comment: Thanks, I am only curious about how what is usual differs by country. From the description it isn’t even clear to me whether they sell that module to end customers or only to providers.

Comment: Its less concerns about countries than than 1) making sure the SFP+ modules is the 'correct' protocol - things like singlemode vs multimode. 2) Some companies also lock down their switches to specific modules

Comment: Well, the product that I linked is from a line of consumer wifi routers that is popular in Germany, and the market may just be different elsewhere.

Comment: Yup - most of my knowledge is from planning (and building parts of) a 10 gig network at home.I'd likely be looking at the options my local ISP offered and talking to people locally if I had multi-gig internet in future. There's a few things that are *isp* specific - ours *all* use gpon with roughly the same ONTs for example (and the ONT acts as a media converter) . I'm vaguely assuming your ISP can advice you on options on connecting from their line or the CPE they provide to something you own.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, thank you so much for your excellent advise. Instead of the UDM pro I went with Unifi's Enterprise 8 switch, but that's pretty much the same thing, except with the 2.5GbE ethernet ports I wanted. Here is my new setup thanks to you: https://imgur.com/gallery/WkmkUR9

Comment: If you don't mind paying it forward, I absolutely would appreciate it if you could post an answer explaining how its set up - does the L3 switching do routing? Do you need any clever vlanning?

Comment: Well, I miss understood the differences between the UDM Pro and the Switch Enterprise 8.  I think I'm going to have to send the Enterprise 8 back.  This is pretty frustrating. If I sub out the Enterprise 8 with the UDM Pro in my diagram, will it get me everything I need?

Comment: the UDM definately will work - that's what its meant for. I THINK a layer 3 switch will do routing, but I've not had the chance to work with one of them to figure out how its set up. https://community.fs.com/blog/layer-2-switch-vs-layer-3-switch-which-one-do-you-need.html is worth a read on that

Answer (score 0):

> Will all my devices that are hard wired to the switch (aka laptop/server) be able to get DHCP from my wireless router some how?

It doesn't really matter. Most likely you're not paying for a class of service where

```
[ISP link] <-> [Switch] <-> [Multiple downstream devices]
```

will do *anything useful at all*, regardless of how you hand out addresses. Generally, your ISP wants to see a single MAC address on your circuit. They tag that address as "yours" for accounting purposes, let it get a public address, and hold onto that association until the link goes down (or longer, if they're not feeling cooperative). Plugging a switch into their Ethernet violates that assumption. It's like every device behind the switch being directly connected to the internet at the same time. One of them may work if you're lucky, the rest get outright ignored.

So you need a router. *Technically* the router doesn't have to be directly connected to the ONT (you could save the switch-in-front topology through clever use of vlans, assuming your switch, and ideally your router, can support that), but even then, all the traffic to or from the internet has to pass *through* the router. Which means you need a device which can route, which has at least one 5 or 10 Gbit port, and which can handle ~5Gbit/s of traffic.

It's not even about NAT, strictly speaking. You could live in an IPv6-only world, with a delegated prefix, and choose to give all of your devices public addresses, thus no NAT, but you would *still* need that router, at least with every residential ISP I've run into. Maybe that will change, but I rather doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging your ISP's fiber into the switch will not work.  The order needs to be:

ISP link --> FIREWALL/ROUTER --> Switch --> End User Devices (Including WAPs).

Some firewalls provide built-in wireless access points and a few switch ports but most high end ones do not.  Almost all firewalls provide a DHCP server built-in.

If your ISP is promising 5Gbps connectivity (this seems unlikely, but is certainly possible I guess), they should also provide you with some firewall/router that can handle 5Gbps.  Keep in mind that in order to actually get wire-speed 5Gbps you need some solid CPU power under the hood.

With regards to DHCP, usually the router does it, but you can always disable the router's DHCP server and run a different one for whatever reason.